# Trying Install Mangento2 in cmd Windows

Tags: php, windows, cmd, magento2

I'm following an internet tutorial to install magento2 and create a project in my PC using Windows cmd.exe.

When I try to install in folder this error shows up:

```
C:\MAMP\htdocs>composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition magento2

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires magento/product-community-edition 2.4.6-p2 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.4.6-p2].
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.4.6-p2 requires ext-gd * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's gd extension.
  Problem 2
    - magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework[4.3.1, ..., 4.4.2] require ext-intl * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's intl extension.
    - Root composer.json requires magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework ^4.3.1 -> satisfiable by magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework[4.3.1, ..., 4.4.2].
```

Comment: Extension intl should be enabled for your php terminal. To do that, go to your php.ini path and uncomment ;extension=intl by removing semicolon. Restart the server again

Answer (score -2):

The error message you're encountering is related to missing PHP extensions required by Magento 2 and its dependencies. To resolve this issue, you need to enable the gd and intl extensions in your PHP configuration. Here are the steps to do that:

**Enable GD Extension:**

Magento 2 requires the GD (Graphics Draw) extension for image processing. To enable it, follow these steps:

1. Open your PHP configuration file (php.ini) in a text editor. The location of this file can vary depending on your PHP installation. Common paths are:

   For MAMP: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php{version}/php.ini

   For XAMPP: C:\xampp\php\php.ini
2. Search for the following line (it might be commented out with a semicolon ;):

```
;extension=gd
```

3. Remove the semicolon ; at the beginning of the line to uncomment it:

```
extension=gd
```

4. Save the php.ini file and restart your web server. In MAMP, you can restart the server from the MAMP application. In XAMPP, use the XAMPP Control Panel to restart Apache.

**Enable Intl Extension:**

Magento 2 also requires the Intl (Internationalization) extension. To enable it:

1. Open your PHP configuration file (php.ini) as mentioned earlier.
2. Search for the following line (it might be commented out with a semicolon ;):

```
;extension=intl
```

3. Remove the semicolon ; at the beginning of the line to uncomment it:

```
extension=intl
```

4. Save the php.ini file and restart your web server.

Verify Extension Installation:

To ensure that the extensions are installed and enabled, you can create a PHP file (e.g., phpinfo.php) with the following content and access it through your web server:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

Search for "gd" and "intl" sections in the PHP info page to confirm that both extensions are enabled.

Retry Magento Installation:

Once you've enabled both extensions and verified their status in the PHP info, try running the Magento installation command again:

```
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition magento2
```

It should now proceed without the previous error.

By enabling the necessary PHP extensions, you'll ensure that Magento 2 and its dependencies have the required functionality to run properly on your system.